# Factorial-based constant

Tags: nt.number-theory, terminology, limits-and-convergence, products

Am looking for a name for:

$$\prod\dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{1}{n!}}$$

$$=2.529477472079152648180116154253954242$$

[Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product%20%28n%21%29%2F%28n%21-1%29)

Expanding the formula gives:

$$(1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{2!^2}+\dots)(1+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{3!^2}+\dots)(1+\frac{1}{4!}+\frac{1}{4!^2}+\dots)\dots$$

which gives the possible denominators used in multinomials.

Comment: Where does this come from? Does it fit into some other area of Mathematics?

Comment: Why close? It quite may be related to some values of known special functions, or exponential generating functions of combinatorial sequences or whatever.

Comment: @FedorPetrov True. But the OP should explain where this comes from.

Comment: The [Plouffe inverter](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advancedCalc) finds no description of this constant (well, I didn't check if the digits given here are correct).

Comment: The digits are easy enough to check (e.g. **prodinf(n=2,1/(1-1/n!))** in **gp**); it seems all are right except the last one (should be 1 instead of 2: 2.529477472079152648180116154253954241[178702394845997…]).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know about a name, but it does have a history. Knopfmacher, Odlyzko, Pittel, Richmond, Stark [D., not H.], Szekeres, and Wormald, The asymptotic number of set partitions with unequal block sizes, available [here](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/EJC/Volume_6/PDF/v6i1r2.pdf), find that it is the residue at $z=1$ of a generating function $$G(z)=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1-{z^k\over k!}\right)^{-1}$$ They relate it to evaluation of sums of multinomial coefficients, and they reference page 126 of Comtet, Advanced Combinatorics.

Comment: Truly, you are wise in the ways of science!

Comment: @Igor, don't tell anyone, but all I did was to type 2.529477 into Google, and up came this reference.

Comment: OK, I won't tell!

Comment: I can see your private talk, please encrypt it! :)